# Wordpress multisite,use same cookies across all website?

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, functions

Hi is this posible to use same custom cookies across all blogs?Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Anybody to help with this?

Comment: Subdirectory, subdomain, or domain mapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across [this support topic](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cookie-error-site-not-letting-me-log-in) which may be helpful. It indicates the following for your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```